# Multiple Cookies in Ajax call

Tags: cookie

I'm experiencing a wierd problem with Magento EE.

In a checkout Ajax call response there are several cookies set, same Cookies multiple times.

Anyone experienced the same problem? Any insight what might be cause for this?

Update: Cookies are

```
CUSTOMER
CUSTOMER_INFO
CUSTOMER_AUTH
CART
CUSTOMER_SEGMENT
```

These are the repeating cookies, CUSTOMER_SEGMENT most often. In addition there are 
COMPARE, VIEWED_PRODUCT_IDS and RECENTLYCOMPARED once.

Comment: Can you update the answer with which cookies those are?